# Crawl and download Readme.md files from GitHub using python

Tags: python, github, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm trying to do an NLP task. For that purpose I need a considerable amount of Readme.md files from GitHub. This is what I am trying to do:

1. For a given number `n`, I want to list the first `n` GitHub repositories (And Their URLs) based on the number of their stars.
2. I want to download the Readme.md file from those URLs.
3. I want to save the Readme.md Files on my hard drive, each in a separate folder. The folder name should be the name of the repository.

I'm not acquainted with crawling and web scraping, but I am relatively good with python. I'll be thankful if you can give me some help on how to accomplish this steps. Any help would be appreciated.

My effort: I've searched a little, and I found a website (gitstar-ranking.com) that ranks GitHub repos based on their stars. But that does not solve my problem because it is again a scraping task to get the name or the URL of those repos from this website.

Comment: You have forgotten to post your attempts at solving your problem yourself. I see you already got the correct terminology, therefore, a google search should yield some results for that topic.

Comment: `GitHub` has an API, this would probably be a good place to start - https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search#search-repositories - for example, that page defines links such as this one - https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E1&sort=stars

Comment: @white You are right. Sorry for that. I added some explanation.

Comment: @Luke That was pretty good. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt using the suggestion from @Luke. I changed the minimum stars to 500 since we don't need 5 million results (>500 still yields 66513 results).
You might not need the ssl workaround on lines 29-30, but since I'm behind a proxy, it's a pain to do it properly.
The script finds files called `readme.md` in any combination of lower- and uppercase but nothing else. It saves the file as `README.md` (uppercase) but this can be adjusted by using the actual filename.

```python
import urllib.request
import json
import ssl
import os
import time


n = 5  # number of fetched READMEs
url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E500&sort=stars'
request = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
page = request.read().decode()
api_json = json.loads(page)

repos = api_json['items'][:n]

for repo in repos:
    full_name = repo['full_name']
    print('fetching readme from', full_name)
    
    # find readme url (case senitive)
    contents_url = repo['url'] + '/contents'
    request = urllib.request.urlopen(contents_url)
    page = request.read().decode()
    contents_json = contents_json = json.loads(page)
    readme_url = [file['download_url'] for file in contents_json if file['name'].lower() == 'readme.md'][0]
    
    # download readme contents
    try:
        context = ssl._create_unverified_context()  # prevent ssl problems
        request = urllib.request.urlopen(readme_url, context=context)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:
        print(error)
        continue  # if the url can't be opened, there's no use to try to download anything
    readme = request.read().decode()
    
    # create folder named after repo's name and save readme.md there
    try:
        os.mkdir(repo['name'])  
    except OSError as error:
        print(error)
    f = open(repo['name'] + '/README.md', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
    f.write(readme)
    print('ok')
    
    # only 10 requests per min for unauthenticated requests
    if n >= 9:  # n + 1 initial request 
        time.sleep(6)
```